# Wordpress rewrite rule with question mark in query

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I’M using a wordpress child theme with a custom template.
The wordpress name of custom template is package and the name of the file is package.php

I create a wordpress page name forfait using this template.

I would like to remove the query parameter

•   [www.mywebsite.com/forfait/?package-id=1234](http://www.mywebsite.com/forfait/?package-id=1234)
To
•   [www.mywebsite.com/forfait/1234](http://www.mywebsite.com/forfait/1234)

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^?]*)\?package-id=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ package.php?package-id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I put this rewrite rule before the rule of Wordpress in the public_html
The rewrite rule work but the page open a 404 page

Comment: Is your htaccess file and package.php residing on same path?

Comment: No if I put htaccess file in the same place of package.php. I don't have any result. Rewrite rule doesn't work.

Comment: Ok sure, I have posted an answer now, we could discuss in its comments section.

Comment: I Lost your answer, can you repost please

Comment: But you said its not working, so I deleted.

Comment: Ok you don't have another solution